# How to Disable Buttons if validations are false

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table data where before proceeding to next step I need to validate few things such as one row should be selected as Key row,Input,Time and Segment row.
I have written code such that until a user doesn't select a key,Time,Row and Segment the next button remains disabled.
However my problem is if the user selects rows as key,Time etc and the Next button gets enabled and then deselects it even then the Next button is enabled.I want it to be disabled if the user deselects the row type(Row type means Key,Input,Segment etc).

```
// Code for Validation of Key and Segment
KeyTimeValidation(event, element) {
if (event.value == 'Key' || event.value == 'Time') {
  let val = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == event.value)
  if (val.length > 1) {
    this.columnList.forEach(column => {
      if (column.columnName === element.columnName) {
        column.type = 'None';
        this.snakbar.statusBar(event.value + ' type cannot be more than one', 'Info');
      }
    })
  }
 const json = JSON.stringify(this.columnList);
  this.columnList = [];
  this.columnList = JSON.parse(json);
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.columnList);

  this.dataSource
    .connect()
    .subscribe(list => this.columnListChange.emit(list));

}
let key = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Key' && column.selected == true);
let time = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Time' && column.selected == true);
let segment = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Segment' && column.selected == true);
let quantile = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Quantile' && column.selected == true);
let input = this.columnList.filter(column => column.type == 'Input' && column.selected == true);
if (key.length >= 1 && time.length >= 1 && (input.length != 0 && (segment.length != 0 || quantile.length != 0))) {
  this.validateSegInput = true;
}
else {
  this.validateSegInput = false;
}
```

}

I have disabled code in my html

```
 <mat-toolbar>
              <button mat-raised-button color="view-data" [disabled]="!validateSegInput" matTooltip="Save Metadata"
                (click)="saveMetadata()" type="button">
                Save
              </button>
              <button color="primary" [disabled]="!validateSegInput" (click)="saveSampleData()" mat-raised-button>
                Next</button>

            </mat-toolbar>
                                                                          What i want is that once the button gets enabled it should get disabled it the condition are false
```

Comment: why dont you put this selection items in form group or form array and then validate
Or
I guess you need to trigger some event on selection of you items and turn your flags on or off then apply condition on base of you flags
Or
you can put the selected items in  a form and make that form hide, and then apply validations on form controls and disable next button according to form valid status

Comment: You mean `[disabled]="!value"`?

Comment: I have updated my question ...please check it once

Comment: @AnsBilal I have set flag and everything.. the thing is initially my Next and Save button are disabled until the conditions are satisfied i.e the user selects Key,Time,Segment etc. The problem is once he selects all these and Next button gets enabled and then if he deselects Key or Time the Next button should get disabled which is not happening in my case

Comment: @saad please create demo of your problem

Comment: @saad Please create a demo at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @saad if selection makes your flags true then you need to make your flag false on deselection. and in template use you one major flag as condition for button enable and disable

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-qw9ncd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts                                                                                         I have created a sample stackblitz demo here ... in this i have to choose Key,Segment... then only next button will get enabled ..i want something similar for my code

Comment: @Justcode I have used [disabled]="!value" in my code